# sqoop import-all-tables fails wilth below error

Tags: sqoop

I am getting this error while executing this `import-all-tables` command:

```
[cloudera@quickstart Desktop]$ sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.26.131/batch31 –-username root –-password cloudera --exclude-tables NYSE_DAILY_PRICES_MYSQL -m1
```

> ```
> Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
> Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
> 18/04/13 10:27:14 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.12.0
> 18/04/13 10:27:14 **ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import-all-tables:**
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Check leading dashes before `username` and `password` params: you need to use `-` instead of `–`.

Comment: Ha, well spotted.